# Почему для Ajax необходим веб-сервер в Chrome?

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Хочу создать локальное приложение на javascript, использую jquery. Мне требуется подгрузить несколько файлов, это я делаю через функцию $.ajax(), но возникает проблема - в Chrome не работает аякс, если страница расположена не на веб сервере. 
Собственно вопрос такой, почему для ajax нужен веб-сервер?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это вопрос безопасности: [Правило ограничения домена](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Правило_ограничения_домена)

Comment: то есть от этой проблемы не избавиться?

Comment: Никогда не видел решений до этого, попробуйте это: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/

Comment: спасибо, буду разбираться

Comment: эта библиотека позволяет совершать кроссдоменные запросы, но локально так же запрещается открывать файлы.

Answer (score 2):

JSONP. [Простой пример](http://lobach.info/develop/javascript/croossdomain-ajax-request/) для `jQuery` и `PHP`.

А еще [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php), если `PHP`.